# Drag an drop file in VUE

Tags: javascript

I need to drag a text file to a dropzone and then read the file in VUE. Seems like an easy thing but I cant figure it out and all the examples and packages (for example vue2-dropzone) uploads the file which I dont want, just read the file.

Thanks for any suggestions or help.

Answer (score -3):

You can't read a file in the web browser directly, this isn't about Vue, it isn't supported in Web.

Comment: You can read a file if a user drags and drops it. Read up on the FileReader API and then rethink your answer.